# Searches for compound words

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, opensearch

I am adding search capabilities to a Swedish recipe site. The problem to solve is compound words. Swedish like all or most Germanic languages compound words to a much larger degree than for example English. So "svamprisotto" is one word consisting of "svamp" (mushroom) and "risotto". If one searches for "risotto" the results should include "svamprisotto" and other variations of risotto.

The solution for this seems to be to use a decompounder. But there does not seem to exist a decompounder for Swedish for OpenSearch, Elasticsearch, Solr. I do not mind building one, but ChatGPT warns against this endeavour as it requires time and knowledge.

I am open for using OpenSearch, Elasticsearch, Solr or anything really. But as I have currently implemented OpenSearch that would be preferable. The budget is somewhat limited, say 200 USD per month during development.

Any recommendations on how I could go about handling compound words on  Swedish recipe site?

Comment: Did you see https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/language-analysis.html#dictionary-compound-word-token-filter ? The same Lucene functionality is available as `dictionary_decompounder` in OpenSearch: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/analyzers/token-filters/index/

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for your suggestion. I am afraid it is more complex that simply an array with words to decomound into. If we take the word "Svamprisotto" it would also be decompounded to "ris"(rice) which would be an incorrect decompounding. So some type of set of rules or hierarchy or words is required to know what to decompound into.

Comment: You can use `onlyLongestMatch` to only get `svamp` and `risotto` in that case - i.e. a substring of a longer match will not be included, even if it matches. But if you want to make this smarter with context of cooking, my suggestion is to either make your own ruleset based on dictionary lookups and hierarchies built from specific domain knowledge or look into NLP in a cooking context.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. I will look into it.